# Magento 2: import large CSV file was not successful

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, import, importexport, image-upload

Magento2 large CSV file was not successfully imported.

I am trying to import 20 Mb products CSV file but was not imported successfully. Still it says "please wait" only.

I have also changed upload_max_filesize = 20M and post_max_size = 20M in  php.ini file and other settings as follows.

```
max_input_time = 300
max_input_time=300
max_execution _time =300
```

Need help

Answer (score 2):

we were facing same issue when importing customer infromation it was like 13000 rows, it worked when we split files of 1000 rows.

a bash command that helped to split quick is:

```
split -l 1000 mybigfile.csv
```

but you have to add the csv headers to each file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please set max execution time  18000
try using collection of 500 product in one csv files , mens at time import 500 then next 500. it work fine try it.

Comment: it is possible to add  22,000 products at once in Magento 2 ???   Need help

Comment: no it create issue like time out , so its advisable to import 500 or 1000 product at time

Comment: But im increase my execution time  any possible to bulk import  plz Ans

Comment: no i dont think , as per my experience not possible

Comment: Bro may i know your working Magento2.0 or Magento 1.9

Comment: i  am working only with magento 2.0

Answer (score 0):

When you import large files you shall consider to import them by the command line.

[Magento 2 Import Performance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178118/magento-2-import-performance) could give you a hint how to get started with it.